# How to make JSON.NET deserialize to Microsoft Date Time?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Using JsonSerializerSettings, I am able to consume/serialize the Microsoft DateTime format, but DateTimes seem continue to deserialize using the ISO 8601 standard

```
JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
                }
```

I'm trying to write a custom JsonConverter to handle the deserialization but am having trouble with the escape characters.

```
writer.WriteValue ("\\/Date(" + x + ")\\/");
```

is writing as

```
"\\/Date(1446145200000)\\/"
```

anyone ever tackled this before?  Been searching around wayy to much without finding a good solution

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need a custom converter here.  Using the `DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat` setting is the correct approach and works both for serialization and deserialization.  Make sure you are passing the settings to the `SerializeObject` and `DeserializeObject` methods as appropriate.  If you don't pass the settings, it will use the default format, which is ISO 8601.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2015,10,29,19,0,0) };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Date.ToString());
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Date": "\/Date(1446145200000+0000)\/"
}
10/29/2015 7:00:00 PM
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hnJIO4

Comment: I'm using the [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/blob/master/Refit) library, which is actually using the `Serialize` and `Deserialize<T>` calls for me (I am passing in the settings I posted above) but looking at the repo it does look like the settings are being used for both methods...strange.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input date has been serialized as ticks. In your custom converter can you deserialize the JSON value and use it to initialize a DateTime object?